# Why is the shadow in the wrong place? (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a green plane, and a red cube over it. The light is a directional light.

[image: shadow]

Why is the shadow in the wrong place?
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/pD8dn/

---

Edit:

If I change the `light.shadowBias` then the shadow on the plane is correct, but the shadow is on the cube incorrect:

[image: shadow]

http://jsfiddle.net/pD8dn/4/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @EmilVikström Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pD8dn/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the most common artefacts for shadow maps, it's called "Peter Panning".

A workaround is to add some small bias for depth testing:

```
light.shadowBias = 0.001;
```

Exact value of the bias needs to be tuned for each scene (and unfortunately sometimes you'll not be able to get rid of all artefacts everywhere, tuning shadow maps is more art than science).

This is what works for your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pD8dn/2/

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, with shadowmaps you need to play with parameters (resolution, light frustum size and position, bias) and find a balance between different types of artefacts. Please note that bias can be very sensitive to tiny variations, experiment with it and see the effects.

Comment: If I have bigger, and smaller objects also in my scene, then I can not find a good solution. Is it a bug in Three.js? Because in the demos of other 3D libraries I haven't found a bug like this.